# NHibernate join query over multiple databases

Tags: nhibernate

I am working on a legacy app and need to query over two tables from two different databases.

Bar the option of selecting both sets of data, then filtering the results are there any other options or best practices for this?

Ideally I would like to run a single query and output the results to a DTO.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping document, specify the table name for the `class` and prefix it w/ the database name and schema name:

```
<class name="BvCustomProduct" table="RelaunchCustom.dbo.bvc_Product">
    ...
</class>
```

NH should join between the two DBs w/ no problem.  This example is for SQL Server, I've not tried it on other dialects but it likely works the same.

Comment: I have two session factories (one for each database) Fully qualifying the mappings will work if I wanted to perform operations on the tables individually but what if I wanted to perform a query that required a join of the two tables?

Comment: Ah.  Can you create a new factory that references the classes from both databases?

Comment: Yes. But how do I create a query that references both table in a join.

Comment: Add a relationship between the two in your object model, just as you would if they were in the same DB.  Or, if they are not related, use a [theta join](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/04/theta-join-in-hql-join-with-unrelated-entities/).